# Is there a localdb equivalent for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In Microsoft SQL Server, localdb can create shallow databases. This is a feature aimed at developers, that creates new databases, without fully copying all data, and it's great for integration testing. Is there an equivalent for PostgreSQL?

Comment: What exactly is a "shallow database"?

Comment: I think the closest thing is [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), which is based on Postgres syntax. Not 100% compatible, but seems to be close enough for most use cases.